# How to solve unbounded interval integral numerically?

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

I am trying to understand something about Numerical Integration using quadratures. I am trying to make transformations to:

$\int_0^\infty f(x)dx,$

In order to find and approximation using composite quadratures like Simpson, Trapezoid, etc. rules.

Reading about it I saw that one of the usual transformations is to use variable substitution like this: $r = x/(1-x)$ and map the interval  $\left[0,\infty  \right)$ to something else. But my problem is I am not quite sure how this works?

I am trying $dr = dx/(1-x)^2$ but I am not sure how to plug it on the integral. Also, tried to change the limits of the intervals as if $x=0$ then $r=0$, but when $x\rightarrow\infty$ then

$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{r} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x/(1-x)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{1/(1-x) - \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{1}} = -1 $

So the new integral limits would be $[0,-1]$, but again, how to I plug in the new limits and transform the integral to match this? Can someone help understand this?

PS: I know such transformation could arise some left/right endpoint singularities but don't want to worry about it right now. Also I know some Gaussian quadratures are capables of solving this type of problems but want to understand this approach.

Comment: The mapping should actually be: $$ x \in [0, \infty) \leftrightarrow r \in [0, 1)$$ via $x=\frac{r}{1-r}$, meaning $r = \frac{x}{1+x}$.

Comment: Then $dr = dx/(1+x)^2$ so $dx=(dr)(1+x)^2=(dr)/(1-r)^2$ and $$\int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_0^1 f\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right)\frac{1}{(1-r)^2}dr$$

Comment: @Michael, thanks. Begining to understand. One question though. How come the right endpoint of the new interval is $1$?.

Comment: I changed the mapping to $r=x/(1+x)$ so we consider the interval $r \in [0,1)$.  Also, that old mapping you suggested ($r=x/(1-x)$)  had a singularity in the middle at $x=1$, which is an unnecessary complication.

Comment: I don't need to do $\int_{-1}^{0}$. I meant, i need help to understand how you came to get the mapping you said.

Comment: It is better to have a smooth mapping, not one with a singularity.  So I slightly modified your existing mapping (which was discontinuous) to a smooth one $[0,\infty) \leftrightarrow [0,1)$.

Comment: I see that now. I noticed the singularity on $x=1$ but did not think of a workaround. You comments had been very helpful. Again, the new mapping you suggested seems perfect for my purpose but I fail to see why is it $r=1$ when $x\rightarrow \infty$ and why is it open?? Also it is expected to use an open quadrature rule? . Hope explaining myself right. PS: i would love to give you an accepted answer if you answer

Comment: @Michael, thanks for your comments. I see it know. Just wasn't computing $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}{x/(1+x)}$ correctly. It is indeed 1.Althought makes me wonder. What would  bethe  error of the numerical computations after using this sort of transformation? Something to think about. Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer summarizes comments above:  The mapping $r = x/(1-x)$ has a pesky singularity at $x=1$.  I would suggest an alternative mapping that has no singularities and that is smooth:
$$ x \in [0, \infty) \leftrightarrow r \in [0,1)$$
via
$$ r = \frac{x}{1+x}$$
which means that $x = r/(1-r)$ and $1+x = 1/(1-r)$.   Then: 
$$ dr = \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2} \implies dx = (dr)(1+x)^2 = \frac{dr}{(1-r)^2}$$
So 
$$ \int_0^{\infty} f(x)dx = \int_0^1 f\left(\frac{r}{1-r}\right)\frac{1}{(1-r)^2}dr$$